# How to get the correct the date-time format for highcharts in R (using rcharts)

Tags: r, highcharts, rcharts

I currently have a dataframe called minuteDataPlot in which I am trying to plot with highcharts in rCharts

```
users      timestamp
1276   2015-10-03 09:00:00
1292   2015-10-03 09:01:00
1306   2014-10-03 09:02:00
```

Here is my code:

```
a <- hPlot(users ~ timestamp, data = minuteDataPlot,
           type = 'spline', title = 'SBK Users per Minute', subtitle = 'Real-Time')
a$global(useUTC = FALSE)
a$xAxis(type='datetime')
a
```

The class for `minuteDataPlot$timestamp`is POSIXlt. My result is

[image: highchart attempt with mydatetime]

You can see that the x-axis does not reflect my timestamp data. I would expect something something similar to my timestamps (e.g 2015-10-03 09:00:00).

I have tried using numeric class as well, but I get the same result. Any help would be grand. I have checked the highcharts documentation as well of course and I can't seem to find any help there.

Comment: AFAIR the javascript libraries referenced in the `rCharts` package handle/expect dates in slightly different format, and when they are converted to JSON something may go wrong. There are several issues with that on the `rCharts` [github page](https://github.com/ramnathv/rCharts/issues/43), but [this trick](https://github.com/ramnathv/rCharts/issues/145) which encapsulates the dates might help you

Comment: Have you tried to use timestamps (time in miliseconds) ?

Comment: Thanks @SebastianBochan. No I haven't. I don't have this data as the above values are aggregated per minute. But, would you suggest simply appending ':00' to the end of my times to satisfy this?

Comment: You can edit [datetime labels](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.dateTimeLabelFormats) by option or use  a [formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.labels.formatter) and return data by [Highcharts.dateFormat](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#Highcharts.dateFormat).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand properly now you have to convert to miliseconds. Here is the code which worked for me:

```
minuteDataPlot2 <- transform(minuteDataPlot,
timestamp2 = as.numeric(as.POSIXct(timestamp))*1000)
```